# convert 24 hour time to am/pm using angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a value

```
$scope.time = 13:30:00 (in 24 hour format)
```

Now I want to change this value to am/pm format using angularjs filter like

```
<th class="text-center">{{time | any filter}}</th>
```

**Output:  1:30 pm**

**Is there any built in filter or do I have to create custom filter?**
**how can I use  "date"  filter to solve this issue?**

Comment: [I'm a little surprised...finding this was a fairly simple Google trip (looking for a date filter).  This is official documentation, too.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: @Makoto You are completely right. The thing, after a while, this answer will be first in google

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak:  We should probably prevent that.  I'm all for letting Stack Overflow's answers really supplant the documentation, but the answer for *this* would *only come from the documentation.*  There's no reason to echo existing information.

Comment: @Makoto The reasons of this question: 1) I am too lazy 2) My english is poor 3) I don't like documentation  4) I am such a beginner that I can not figure out from doc

Comment: I'm not interested in enabling your laziness.  I can appreciate that documentation isn't the most enjoyable read, but just because you don't *want* to read it doesn't mean you should ask the question here and expect anything *other* than a reference to the documentation.

Comment: Why to ask when it is already in official documentation. You can go through that documentation.

Comment: @Makoto Here we should consider OP's reputation to see if the situation comforts 2,4

Comment: Probably its high time for StackOverflow to put a banner "Don't ask anything which has any reference out there for!"

Comment: ohhh.. @Makoto, Don't you think I tried the documentation!!!
@ asdf_enel_hak It's obvious that you might know better but the attitude does not completes my question.

Comment: can anyone try this to covert "13:30:00" to "1:30 pm"? This will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
$scope.time = 2016-03-28T13:30:00
instead of $scope.time = 13:30:00

Comment: So, without proper format of "date" it won't work. Thank you @Pavel.

Answer (score 2):

```
{{time | date:"h:mma"}}
```

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) are the formats.

Comment: if I change the value into a proper format like  **2016-03-28T13:30:00** only then it works.. Thanks buddy @Charlie H

Comment: hey Charlie the above format won't work in angularJS, i wanted to show only time like 7:30PM, do you know custom filter for time only.

Answer (score 0):

html use

```
{{d.date | timeDate}}
```

js filter

```
app.filter('timeDate', function() {
    return function(value){
        value = new Date(value);
        return (value.getHours()>=13?(value.getHours()-12):(value.getHours())) + ":" + (value.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + value.getMinutes() + (value.getHours()>11?'pm':'am');
    }
});
```

this will convert 
"Fri Nov 16 12:35:42 MST 2018"
to
"12:35pm"